# What is the effect of git commit without the -a option?

Tags: git, commit

What is the difference between these two commands?

```
git commit -m "added a new page"
```

and

```
git commit -a -m "added a new page"
```

I know that the -a option will stage files that have been modified and deleted, but then what does running it without the -a mean?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have to explicitly stage changes for commitment by using `git add` or `git rm`.

If you use the `-a` flag when doing a commit, git will automatically stage any modified and removed files without you having to explicitly stage them using `add` or `rm`, etc.

If you *don't* specify `-a`, any files that have been modified or removed, but not explicitly staged using `git add` or `git rm` will be ignored in the commit.

*update*

As Dr. Gianluigi Zane Zanettini says - `-a` does not add *new* files to the index, so if you have completely new files you shouldn't expect `-a` to ad them.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html

Comment: A small note: `-a` works only for modified/delete files. Per git documentation, new files are not affected: `but new files you have not told Git about are not affected.` => It's almost always better to do `git add .` instead of `git commit -a`.

Comment: Gianluigi, thanks, but it does not tell anything new, John already said that with "explicitly staged with gid add". Another thing worse mentioning: One can also use git commit -am.