# What does "-a" mean when using Git?

Tags: git, commit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git commit -a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807899/git-commit-a-question)

If we have this Git command:

```
> git commit -a -m "abc"
```

What does `-a` mean?

Thanks.

Comment: While I am all for Stackoverflow helping people, I find this question ridiculous. How much time would it have taken to see what this does in the docs? You were using it / knew about. Not like it was other way around where you wanted to do something.

Answer (score 4):

It means that Git will automatically include any modified files in the commit. However, it will not include untracked files.

Answer (score 4):

It is equal to `--all` and means that all modified or deleted files (stage) are automatically committed. This do not includes unstaged files. See [man](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html).

Answer (score 3):

`git help commit` says:

```
  -a, --all
       Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told git about are not
       affected.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `git add` command has similar but different options which can cause confusion, e.g. its `-A .` option.

As others have said it (`-a`) requests that all modifications, including deletions, to the current set of files that you already have in the staging area will be included in the commit.

Having performed the commit, the files are still there in the staging area waiting to be included in the next commit, unless you expressly remove them with a command or an option. This is 'tracking'.

If you have new files you want to include you need to `git add` them.

My visualisation is that the staging area is like a pin board that holds a copy of the items I've 'finished' (added/updated), and if I commit, then a complete copy of the pin board is taken. Git can then tell the differences between what's on my desk (working directory), the 'finished' work I've pinned to the pin board (staged), and the last commit snapshot of it all together. I had to remember the need to take things down from the pin board (remove from the staging area) when files were deleted.